# SEM design on dyadic data. Please help!

Tags: factor-analysis, model, structural-equation-modeling, dyadic-data

I have two surveys, and one is implemented to counselors. The questions ask about they feel about their relationship with their administrator. It has have two dimensions, let's say d1 and d2. I have the scores on each questions and on the two dimensions (which is just aggregating the scores questions from each dimension). The other one is implemented to patients. The questions ask about they feel about their relationship with their counselors. It has three dimensions, let's say d3,d4, and d5. Again, I have the scores on each questions and on the three dimensions.

I am trying to build a SEM model to answer the question that whether the counselors' feeling about the relationship between the supervisor and them predict patients' feeling about the relationship between the counselors and the patients?

However, I have two problems:

1. Should this case still be considered as dyadic data?
2. There are multiple patients seeing one counselor and multiple counselor seeing one patient at different time. We do not consider time difference. But given it is so complicated. How can I design my model?

Thanks so much for anyone that have an answer.